# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate query return nothing when using aggregate functions

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I encountered a situation like following while using **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate** in a spring boot project with **postgreSQL**

I have the following code.

```
SalesDto salesDto = new SalesDto();
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT SUM(asts.downloads) AS downloads, SUM(asts.amount_earned) " +
            "AS earnings FROM t_asset_sale asts", rs -> {
        if (rs.next()) {
            salesDto.setEarnings(rs.getDouble("earnings"));
            salesDto.setDownloads(rs.getInt("downloads"));
        }
    });
```

And the earnings and download values are not assigned to the salesDto object. I debugged the code too and found that lines inside the **if** statement is not get executed.

But when I add a return statement,

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT SUM(asts.downloads) AS downloads, SUM(asts.amount_earned) " +
            "AS earnings FROM t_asset_sale asts", rs -> {
        if (rs.next()) {
            salesDto.setEarnings(rs.getDouble("earnings"));
            salesDto.setDownloads(rs.getInt("downloads"));
        }
        return salesDto;
    });
```

then the values are assigned to the dto object. Even I return a **new Object()**

```
return new Object();
```

Instead of salesDto, the lines inside gets executed. So what is the impact of return statement? I mean there are no errors; I do not even have a return statement. Can someone explain what is happening here.
I am in java 8, postgres 13 and spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a method named `query` with 2 parameters, the first parameter being a `String`.

There are 3 overloads for that:

- [`void query(String sql, RowCallbackHandler rch)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler-)
- [`<T> T query(String sql, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-)
- [`<T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-)

Since you're passing a lambda expression as the second parameter, we need to look at the functional interfaces of those 3:

- [`void processRow(ResultSet rs)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html#processRow-java.sql.ResultSet-)
- [`T extractData(ResultSet rs)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html#extractData-java.sql.ResultSet-)
- [`T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html#mapRow-java.sql.ResultSet-int-)

Since the lambda expression only takes 1 argument, the 3rd overload is out, leaving 2 choices for the compiler:

- Without a `return` statement, only the `void` method is valid, so compiler chooses the `RowCallbackHandler` overload.
- With a `return` statement, the compiler might fail with "ambiguous" error message, or it may choose the `ResultSetExtractor` overload.
  It seems your compiler chose the 2nd overload.

Javadoc of the 2 methods:

> **Interface RowCallbackHandler**
>
> Consider **using a RowMapper** instead if you need to map exactly one result object per row, assembling them into a List.
>
> *void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException*
>
> Implementations must implement this method to process **each row** of data in the ResultSet. This method **should not call next()** on the ResultSet; it is only supposed to extract values of the current row.

---

> **Interface ResultSetExtractor**
>
> *T extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException*
>
> Implementations must implement this method to process the **entire ResultSet**.

Without a `return` statement, the framework has already called `next()`, so when you call `next()`, it returns false, and skips the code. With a `return` statement, you're supposed to call `next()` repeatedly until all rows are processed.

The correct way to use the 2 overloads are as follows, with casts to functional interfaces to eliminate method overload ambiguity:

```java
String sql = "SELECT SUM(asts.downloads) AS downloads" +
                  ", SUM(asts.amount_earned) AS earnings" +
              " FROM t_asset_sale asts";
```

```java
// RowCallbackHandler
SalesDto salesDto = new SalesDto();
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, (RowCallbackHandler) rs -> {
    salesDto.setEarnings(rs.getDouble("earnings"));
    salesDto.setDownloads(rs.getInt("downloads"));
});
```

```java
// ResultSetExtractor
SalesDto salesDto = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, (ResultSetExtractor) rs -> {
    if (! rs.next())
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException("Aggregated query", 1);
    SalesDto salesDto = new SalesDto();
    salesDto.setEarnings(rs.getDouble("earnings"));
    salesDto.setDownloads(rs.getInt("downloads"));
    return salesDto;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this well explained answer. Seems like I should have dig deeper :).